# how to parse xml geocoding results in java using JDOMParser

Tags: java, xml, parsing

I am developing an application which uses geocoding results received from the http. I want to parse the result which is in xml format and extract the longitude and latitude data. How can I parse the result using JDOMParser?

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at this tutorial:

http://www.journaldev.com/1206/jdom-parser-read-xml-file-to-object-in-java

It helped me, but I ended up using SAX Parser instead and applied a schema for validation.